# Duplicate sources.list entry Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-sources

I'm trying to install one software but showing this error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried editing `sources.list` and commenting out the duplicate entry? `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and place a `#` in front of the duplicate entry, then save.

Comment: Thx it worked...

Comment: PUT it as an answer...thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit `sources.list` and comment out the duplicate entry.

- Edit `sources.list`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- Place a `#` in front of the duplicate entry
- Save:

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Update:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

Now try again.

Comment: Also watch out for entries under individual files @ `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`