# Duplicate sources warning found while updating

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I run,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

the terminal gives me,

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: please read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry

Answer (score 0):

Edit `sources.list` and comment out the duplicate entry.

- Edit `sources.list`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- Place a `#` in front of the duplicate entry
- Save:

  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Update:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

Now try again.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456321/duplicate-sources-list-entry-ubuntu-14-04/500546#500546)

Comment: actually, the google chrome entry should be found in an individual file under the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d